# can facebook authentiation tokens be shared between applications

Tags: iphone, web-services, facebook

I have a mobile app that allows users to login through facebook connect.
There is also a webservice that the mobile app will use.

Can the mobile app share its auth token with the webservice?

1. user login to facebook through mobile app
2. mobile app sends auth token to webservice
3. webservice queries facebook for user details

or would the mobile app query facebook and then pass the information to the webservice?

1. user login to facebook through mobile app
2. mobile app queries facebook for user details
3. mobile app sends details to webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The API doesn't care where you get the token from, as long as you're using the same AppID/Secret. This is commonly used in offline data access scenarios (user authenticates through web app, backend service updates in background). Do you have a specific example where this doens't work?

Comment: What if the web service is another App with different AppID? Can I avoid forcing the user login twice?